# Laravel Netshel/Paypal Suddenly Does Not Work, String Conversion Error

Tags: laravel, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

So after doing a `composer update` with Laravel, My Netshell/Paypal Package seems to be haywired.  And is not functioning as intended to be when checking-out a Paypal transaction.

The error seems to occur here

```
$payment = PayPal::Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale');
$payment->setPayer($payer);
$payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
$payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

Log::info(print_r($payment, true));

// ERROR PART HERE
$response = $payment->create($this->_apiContext);
$redirectUrl = $response->links[1]->href;
```

The error occurs on this line of code

```
$payment->create($this->_apiContext);
```

When calling the `create()` method by passing the `_apiContext`

This is the error it throws

> 2019-12-08 01:09:21] local.ERROR: Array to string conversion
>   {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Array to string
>   conversion at D:\Workspace Ampps\www\itt\vendor\paypal\
>   est-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Handler\OauthHandler.php:57)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**My Keys for the Paypal in the .env file was lost that's why it throws that error**